# É possível abrir o arquivo para escrita e ao mesmo tempo abrir para leitura sem antes fechar em C?

Tags: c, sistema-de-arquivos

Não é um boa prática de programação?

```
void leitura(FILE *arq)
{
  if((arq = fopen("dificuldade.txt","r")) == NULL)
    printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n"); 
  else
  {
    //linhas de codigo
    fclose(arq); 
  }
}

void impressao(FILE *arq)
{
  int i;

  if((arq = fopen("dificuldade.txt","w")) == NULL)
    printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
  else
  {
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
       {
         //linhas de codigos
         leitura(arq); 
         //Estou no loop e quero fazer a leitura a cada impressão
         //Cada impressão no ciclo, quero ler e manipular aqueles dados
         //Como faço isso, pois tenho que fechar o arquivo... ?
       }
    fclose(arq);
  }
}

main()
{
  FILE *arq;
  impressao(arq);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você deveria usar "r+", para ler e escrever, preservando o conteúdo original

Comment: Em todos colocar "r+" e o "fclose" permanece onde está? sem fechar o arquivo durante a impressão para  depois fazer a leitura?

Comment: Abre o arquivo somente uma vez com o "r+", e trabalha com `fputs()`, `fgets()` e etc..

Comment: Se após escrever você quiser voltar para o início do arquivo utiliza a função rewind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É boa prática fechar sempre que abre um arquivo de texto.
Com a tabela que está incluida em anexo dá para ver algumas funcionalidades que poderá implementar para ler e escrever.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estas funções a baixo servem para ler e escrever no arquivo de texto.

```
void fprintf (FILE *fluxo, char *formatação, ...);
int fwrite (void *dados, int tamanho_do_elemento, int num_elementos, FILE *fluxo);
```

Mais informação acerca de ficheiros de texto recomendo o [wikibooks](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_em_arquivos)

Comment: Está difícil implementar isso lá no código, pois tenho que abrir o arquivo e fazer a impressão e com ele aberto tenho que fazer a leitura e manipular os dados...